# C++ and Python SWIG Bindings Using Previously Created Dynamic Shared Library

Tags: python, c++, binding, cmake, swig

I am wrapping C++ code for use in Python using SWIG. The C++ module I am wrapping has C++ dependencies of other modules located within a different package. However, rather than directly importing/including these files, I would like to import a previously created Python library/dynamic shared library to deal with the dependencies. I want to use this method because I do not want to hard-code files in this package for them to work. I will simply have access to the shared library.

Currently, without importing the library, compiling the new module with the wrapper file results in the error:
  "fatal error: string: No such file or directory compilation terminated."
as a header file the new module depends on is not available within this package. I do not want to copy the required headers the new module has a dependency on into this package.

I would like to know if this is possible within either the SWIG interface file or CMake.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, perhaps if you post the Python code that you would be able to write, and which parts of the code come from which module, and which modules are wrapped with SWIG, then your question would be clearer.

Comment: If the C++ code is calling other C++ code then those other libraries need to be linked too in '.so' .  Which means that you need to have at least the headers for those other libraries available at the compile/linking stage. The python vm expects to able to hand the computation off entirely to the .so layer.